# Copying and Pasting a Range of Cells from One Worksheet to Another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a range of cells from one worksheet (Sheet2) to a different range of cells in another worksheet (Sheet1) but when I run the below, I get a run time error (1004) application defined or object defined error. Any help is appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Sub deletecolumns()

Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Columns(2).Select
Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Columns(2).Delete


Sheets("Sheet2").Range("I4:I29").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H4:H29")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

delete this line:

```
Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Columns(2).Select
```

there's no need for it before doing a `.delete` anyway

Comment: The reason this fails is because you probably do not have the `Worksheets(1)` activated.  You are not allowed to `Select` on a `Worksheet` that is not active.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, @Byron. I avoid `.select` whenever possible, so I don't know all the pitfalls...

Comment: Unfortunately, we all had to start somewhere.  I started with a healthy dose of `Select` `Activate` and `Cells(i,j)` before I learned how to do it proper.

Comment: I hear ya. I recommend Macro Recorder to learn how to do things (and figure out esoteric font settings, etc), but also point people to [tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) to avoid using select.